# Windows Phone, ItemsControl.ContainerFromIndex returns null

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, itemscontrol

I've got a templated control. Part of the template looks like the following:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="icSubObjects">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:StateButton Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

ItemsSource for this panel is being set from code behind.

Then in code I'm trying to access the actual objects generated from data:

```
for (int i = 0; i < icSubObjects.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var element = icSubObjects.ContainerFromIndex(i);
    if (element is StateButton)
    {
        var btn = element as StateButton;

        // btn is always null, despite icSubObjects.Items.Count being > 0
    }                    
}
```

After caling `icSubObjects.ContainerFromIndex(i)`, I always get null, despite fact, that objects are correctly displayed and `icSubObjects.Items.Count` is greater than 0. What can I do to make this method work correctly? (or what am I doing wrong?)

---

**Edit:** The plot unfolds

I found on the Internet a trick, which fixes the problem. The trick is to "touch" `Children` property of one of containers, which holds the `ItemsControl` control:

```
var temp = gContainer.Children;
```

The containers are then populated correctly.

I've got another problem though. From `ContainerFromIndex` I get the ContentPresenter. How can I access `StateButton`, which is inside `DataTemplate` of that `ContentPresenter`?

Comment: @Clemens You actually tried to answer my next question, which I didn't yet asked :) My problem was solved by - as found somewhere on the Internet - "touching" `Children` property of container, on which `ItemsControl` is placed. Now I get these `ContentPresenter`s, but casting their `Content` property to `StateButton` returns null. It looks like `Content` of `ContentPresenter` is simply a string. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I was on the wrong track. The StateButton is *not* put into the Content property. In WPF, you would get it by naming it in XAML (by setting e.g. `x:Name="sb"` and then calling `element.ContentTemplate.FindName("sb", element)` (where element is the ContentPresenter). Not sure if this will work in Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the comments below the question, I understand that you already know why `btn` is always null (although, I guess it's not even entering that `if` statement). Anyway, I'll say it again for anyone who wants to know.

`ContainerFromIndex` **returns a ContentPresenter** (in most cases). **Not a StateButton**.

Now, to get the `StateButton` that you want from the ContentPresenter, I think you can do this:

```
var btn = (StateButton)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(contentPresenter, 0);
```

If that doesn't work (that is, the StateButton isn't the only and first child of the ContentPresenter), just check the visual tree and modify the code to get the element that you need from the tree.